# What does it mean that "what am I like"?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean that you try telling me something about me?

Comment: "What am I like" is a question, though perhaps a rhetorical one.  Could have several different meanings, depending on context.

Comment: I already forgot where I saw it, but you can made me know another meaning, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, 'What am I like?' could have two meanings depending on the intonation.

If you were to ask someone, with sincerity, 'what am I like?', then yes, it means as you suggest, tell me what I am like (something about myself).

If someone has done something silly and asks, '*what* am I *like*?' with emphasis and raised pitch on 'what' and 'like', it then becomes a rhetorical question - more of a statement.